# s3 connection to 'folder' via boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to upload a file to a specific location using boto and python.  I'm accessing using something to this effect:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key


conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('the_bucket_name')
for key in bucket: 
    print key.name
```

Here's the trick.   I have been provisioned credentials to a 'folder' within a bucket.  per this - [Amazon S3 boto - how to create a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939743/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-create-folder) I understand that there actually aren't folders in s3, rather keys like "foo/bar/my_key.txt". when i try to execute get_bucket() I get

`boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden`

because i dont actually have credentials to the base bucket, rather a subset of the bucket keys.  `my_bucket/the_area_I_have_permission/*`

Does anyone know how I could pass the specific 'area' in the bucket i have access to in the connection step? or an alternative method i can use to access `my_bucket/the_area_I_have_permission/*`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.  [RequestTimeTooSkewed Error using PHP S3 Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749156/requesttimetooskewed-error-using-php-s3-class)

The issue was my VM date was off and amazon uses the date to validate the request.  1+ to @bdonlan.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help :

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket('the_bucket_name',validate=False)

key = bucket.get_key("ur_key_name")
if key is not None:
    print  key.get_contents_as_string()

keys = bucket.list(prefix='the_area_I_have_permission')
for key in keys:
    print key.name
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  nope.  got TypeError: get_key() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix' for the first and boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden for the second.

Comment: Ohh mixed two different API calls. This one should be the call. 

Regarding 403, Are you able to access the bucket using some other clinet(may be UI or S3Explorer plugin for Firefox) with these secretid/keys ?

Comment: dang.  I still get a 403 for the first. I'm trying to connect with "bucket-name", then i'm passing the path to the file i'm trying to access ie: "/some/path/file.json".  is that correct?  i've tried with and without the leading slash.

Comment: as for the 403, yes.  I connect just fine with s3uploader BUT if i try to navigate anywhere but the specific folder i've been provisioned creds for, I get the error